# Php FOPEN - CENTOS 7 - Cant Create File or Folder

Tags: php, centos7, fopen

**EDIT 01 UPDATE:**

> ERROR Showing UP Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in
> /var/www/html/projeto01/index.php on line 7 Sucess. Dir Created

**EDIT 02**

Change to FEDORA and is working.

Thank you guys

---

before submitting this topic I read and tried all the topics here. No success.

The environment is working great until here. Php 7.4, Apache, Mysql Workbench, Atom... i can code and select from database, everything was great.

The code is working with no error execpt it did not create the directory. :/ 
If i create the dir manually, return the message that it already exist.

After read a lot of topics and get help from facebook.
I did change on group polices. Not worked.
chmod on the folder, not worked.

On CENTOS the apache user is APACHE instead www:data

```
ls -l /var/www    return:
drwxr-x---. 2 apache apache  6 Nov 16 13:19 cgi-bin
drwxrwxrwx. 3 apache apache 39 Mar 19 13:54 html

ls -l /var/www/html    return:
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root   86 Mar 19 00:09 info.php
drwxrwxrwx. 2 apache apache 23 Mar 19 13:58 projeto01

ls -l /var/www/html/projeto1    return:
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 148 Mar 19 15:14 index.php
```

Thanks for the help!

My code is:

```
> <?php

$name = "images";

if (!is_dir($name)) {
  mkdir($name);
  echo "Sucess. Dir Created.";
} else {
  echo "Dir already exist. $name";

}


?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Whats your output? Have you checked the web server error log?

Comment: there is no error. :/  
im running on locally.

Comment: So you are running this from the CLI?

Comment: Try using `$name = "./images";` or the complete path: `$name = "/var/www/html/projeto1/images";`

Comment: tried. didnt work.  :(